# key presses go crazy after Android adb device is connected

Tags: usb, keyboard, android

I have an issue with one machine of mine that is running Ubuntu 16.04.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Connect Android device via USB
2. run "adb devices"
3. Start typing

The key presses start malfunctioning like I'm holding a key down when in reality I have removed my hands completely.  The situation can be fixed only by removing the Android device USB connection.

I have tried multiple Android devices and they all have the same issue.  I also have several other colleagues with the exact same PC hardware setup and they don't have the issue.  Can anyone suggest how I might be able to debug the issue to see what the problem is?

EDIT:

evtest log (device plugged in just before the "k" was pressed):

```
Event: time 1498086624.661268, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70028
Event: time 1498086624.661268, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 28 (KEY_ENTER), value 0
Event: time 1498086624.661268, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086627.085272, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70009
Event: time 1498086627.085272, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 33 (KEY_F), value 1
Event: time 1498086627.085272, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
fEvent: time 1498086627.141262, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70009
Event: time 1498086627.141262, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 33 (KEY_F), value 0
Event: time 1498086627.141262, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086634.805269, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7000a
Event: time 1498086634.805269, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 34 (KEY_G), value 1
Event: time 1498086634.805269, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
gEvent: time 1498086634.869271, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7000a
Event: time 1498086634.869271, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 34 (KEY_G), value 0
Event: time 1498086634.869271, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.165257, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 7000e
Event: time 1498086646.165257, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 1
Event: time 1498086646.165257, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
kEvent: time 1498086646.415080, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
Event: time 1498086646.415080, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.451088, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
Event: time 1498086646.451088, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.487099, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
Event: time 1498086646.487099, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.523132, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
Event: time 1498086646.523132, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.559089, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
Event: time 1498086646.559089, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1498086646.595088, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 37 (KEY_K), value 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I had a powered 4 port USB hub that my keyboard was plugged in to like [this](http://www.ncix.com/detail/belkin-f4u027-4-port-usb-47-63793.htm) one.  When I connected my keyboard directly to the PC the problem goes away.